# Performing job array by reading in file paths from a text file

Tags: bash, shell-script, path, array

I am trying to perform a job array using script below.

```
#!/bin/bash --login
#$ -cwd
#$ -t 1-4

module load apps/bioinf
module load apps/trimmomatic/0.36/noarch

file=`awk "NR==$SGE_TASK_ID" ~/scratch/Genome/single_reads.txt`

trimmomatic SE $file $(basename $file) SLIDINGWINDOW:5:20 MINLEN:35
```

It worked previously when it read a text file with just the names of files in the current directory. For example the original text file called single_reads.txt contained:

ERR179588.fastq.gz
ERR179589.fastq.gz
ERR179590.fastq.gz and so on...

I'm now trying it with a file path listed per row instead of just the file name. Such as:

~/scratch/fasta_files/ERR1795288.fastq.gz.
~/scratch/fasta_files/ERR1795289.fastq.gz and so on...

I keep getting this error:

```
TrimmomaticSE: Started with arguments:
~/scratch/fasta_files/ERR1795288.fastq.gz ERR1795288.fastq.gz SLIDINGWINDOW:5:20 MINLEN:35
Automatically using 1 threads
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: ~/scratch/fasta_files/ERR1795288.fastq.gz (No such file or directory)
```

Maybe it's seeing the file path as just a filename in my current directory, rather than a file in a different directory.

Sorry if this is basic, I'm new to bash!

Comment: you could just change the path from `~/scratch...` to a full path e.g. `/home/<user>/scratch/...`

Comment: @suspectus Hi, I've just tried changing it to the full file path and it still returns no such file or directory error

Comment: Please show your full script. Add some debug output that prints the file name or use `set -x` to make your shell print all commands before executing.